# Showing a function is not a bijection

Tags: calculus, functions

Let $g: [1,2] \rightarrow (3,5)$ be one-to-one and continuous. Show that $g$ is not onto using the intermediate value theorem.

I figured I can show $g$ is a strictly increasing or decreasing function, but how should I proceed from there?

Comment: suppose g is increasing... $g(2)\in (3,5)$ so it is an interior point since (3,5) is open so there exists some $ y\in(3,5)$ & $y>g(2)$ so y has no preimage...similarly for decreasing case

Answer (score 2):

If $g$ is say increasing (a similar argument for decreasing), then $g(1)\in (3,5)$.  But then there are elements in $(3,5)$ that are less than $g(1)$.  Could these values (less than $g(1)$) be in the range of $g$?

Answer (score 0):

We don't need the fact that $g$ is one to one. If $g$ is continuous on $[0,1]$, therefore $g([1,2])$ has to be an interval. Let denote $[a,b]:=g([1,2])$. Therefore $[a,b]\subset (3,5)$ by definition. Moreover $(3,5)$ is an open interval and thus, there is a $\delta>0$ such that $a-\delta\in (3,5)$, but $g^{-1}(a-\delta)=\emptyset$ and thus $g$ is not onto and thus not bijective.

Comment: but how can u suppose that the inverse exists by using g−1(a−δ) with "g" being a non bijective mapping ?

Comment: Here $g^-1(a-\delta)$ is being used to mean preimage rather than the inverse of g, defined as the set of x in the domain such that $g(x) = a-\delta $

Comment: First, $\;g\;$ is defined on $\;[1,2]\;$ , not $\;[0,1]\;$. Second, $\;g[1,2]\;$ indeed is an interval, but why did you write it is a *closed* one? This is in fact the gist of the problem, imo.

Comment: It's a consequence of the intermediate value theorem, if $g:[c,d]\to \mathbb R$, then $g([c,d])=[\min_{[c,d]}g,\max_{[c,d]}g]$.

Comment: Of course with $g$ continuous. But is my proof wrong ?